# How do you stop infix_notation from matching the base expression when there are no operations (pyparsing)?

Tags: python, keyword, pyparsing, infix-notation

I am trying to parse expressions with pyparsing, and can do that with `infix_notation`, but the problem is that it matches lines that have no operations, and just match the base_expr argument. This is a problem because valid keywords can be matched by the base_expr.

I use this as the infix_notation

```
expression = infix_notation(Word(
    printables,
    exclude_chars="** ~ + - * / % & | ^ != == <= >= < > ! , += -= *= /= %= <<= >>= &= |= ^="
),
                            [
                                ("**", 2, OpAssoc.LEFT),
                                (one_of("~ + -"), 1, OpAssoc.RIGHT),
                                (one_of("* / % *= /= %="), 2, OpAssoc.LEFT),
                                (one_of("<< >> <<= >>="), 2, OpAssoc.LEFT),
                                (one_of("& | ^ &= |= ^="), 2, OpAssoc.LEFT),
                                (one_of("+ - += -="), 2, OpAssoc.LEFT),
                                (one_of("!= == <= >= < >"), 2, OpAssoc.LEFT),
                                (one_of("&& ||"), 2, OpAssoc.LEFT),
                                ("!", 1, OpAssoc.RIGHT),
                            ])
```

The problem match is this

```
Word(
    printables,
    exclude_chars="** ~ + - * / % & | ^ != == <= >= < > ! , += -= *= /= %= <<= >>= &= |= ^="
)
```

So this would match the keyword "else" which I do not want, but it also needs to match variables in an expression like "else1 += else2".

How would you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to differentiate keywords from identifiers is to define an expression for any keyword like this (get the list of all Python keywords, but you can define your own list):

```
from keyword import kwlist
any_keyword = pp.one_of(kwlist, as_keyword=True)

infix_term = Word(
    printables,
    exclude_chars="** ~ + - * / % & | ^ != == <= >= < > ! , += -= *= /= %= <<= >>= &= |= ^="
)

operand = ~any_keyword + infix_term

expression = infix_notation(operand, 
    ... etc. ...
```

Note that your `Word(printables, ...)` expression for an infix_term will match almost anything, including `......`, integers, floats, etc. Also, the exclude_chars argument does not split the string into operators, but just uses all the chars in the string. So you would not be able to use "-10" as a term, since "-" is in the set of exclude_chars. So give a little more thought as to how to best define your operands.

Lastly, your infix_notation list of operators is pretty long, and this will be a sloooooooowwwww parser if you don't enable packrat parsing (using `ParserElement.enable_packrat()`.

Comment: ~any_keyword works partly. If the beginning of an operand matches a keyword, it will fail to parse an operand. Like ```list_index += 1```  fails to be parsed because "li" appears as one of the keywords.

Comment: Regarding the -10. Doesn't the unary operation "-" make it so -10 is an operand?

Comment: The leading 'li' in 'list_index' should not match the keyword for 'li' if you define 'li' as a Keyword, not as a Literal, or if you add 'as_keyword=True' in the call to `one_of`.

Comment: Unary minus will probably save you in this respect. But in general `Word(printables)` often matches characters that were not expected, so I caution people against this. But it is not always fatal, and you may have already addressed the possible error cases.

Comment: That is the part I missed. I actually ended up doing this ```(~(keywords + Literal(whitespace))```, but your way looks better.

Comment: Right - there is not always whitespace after a keyword, as in "if(x==1 or y==2)"

Comment: You probably want to exclude '()'s from your `Word(printables)` too.